# Linux: set up media server to stream video via the Internet?

Tags: linux, internet, streaming, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

How do I set up a media server in Linux which streams video over the internet?

Is it easy to do this? I want a server that will actually encode video in real time to allow it to stream over sometimes slow or unreliable networks. Basically, I want a server that works on the internet.

I have a directory with a bunch of video files, and want to make this accessible to myself remotely.

For other situations, I found great and useful software (such as the PS3 media server). I'd like to find something equally as useful for streaming video over the internet.

Comment: VLC possibly might work for you here.

Comment: PLEX: http://www.plexapp.com/

SubSonic: http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp

Both are easy to setup and will stream video, music, etc over the internet to your phone or web browser.

Comment: @Atari911 I've actually been using Plex for a while now. It's hands down the best solution I've found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with ffserver(a component of ffmpeg).  Details [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.